# PowerShell - Renaming files that have the same basename

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames, clr

I am trying to update a .wav file as well as a .txt file with a newname pulled from the .txt file.

I only need the files that have the same basename before the update, to update with the new name I get from the txt files.

Example

94951595.txt - get contents = hello
So new name will be hello

94951595.wav - I need the matching .wav file to also change to hello.

and vice versa for 94951598

[image]

Below is the code I use to update the .txt files on their own from the get-content.

I am struggling how to add the .wav -filter or -match in there

```sh
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem c:\test\*.txt
>> foreach ($File in $txtFiles) {
>>     $File.fullname
>>     $Data = (get-content $File.fullname)[6,7,4]-Join 1
>> $Data = $Data -Replace ":",","
>>     $Rename = (Rename-item $file -NewName $file$data)
>> }
```

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What exactly are you doing here? You are reading a text file, replace a character and create a file name of the existing file name AND the data within the text file? What are the contents of the text file and what are you trying to do with the .wav files?

Comment: That is because you are explicitly filtering for text files in the first line of code. Do the same for the wav files.

Comment: You just take the name from the txt file... Filter for txt and wav and generate file name with the content of the txt and rename both files. There isn't much to help here. You just have to get the wav and do the same rename operation on it within the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)
to combine the files with equal BaseNames (the filename without extension), loop over these groups and perform the rename on each item in the group based on whatever is in the .txt file.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test' -File | Where-Object { '.txt','.wav' -contains $_.Extension }
# if you need to recurse through subfolders, use:
# $files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test' -File -Include '*.txt', '*.wav' -Recurse

# next group the files on their BaseName, process only groups wherein there are two (or more) files 
# with equal BaseNames and loop over the groups
$files | Group-Object {$_.BaseName} | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1} |
ForEach-Object {
    # from within the group get the text file containing the new name
    $txtFile = $_.Group | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.txt' }
    if ($txtFile) {
        $newName = (Get-Content -Path $txtFile.FullName -TotalCount 1).Trim()  # read just the first line
        $_.Group | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1}' -f $newName, $_.Extension} -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Please note that I have added a `-WhatIf` switch to the Rename-Item cmdlet. This is a safety measure and with that switch, you will only see a line in the console telling you what action *would* be performed.
Nothing actually gets renamed.
Once you are satisfied with all console messages that everything does what is expected, you can remove these `-WhatIf` switch.